# Sorting pictures into folders by date taken

Tags: c#, sorting, image

I want to make software that groups pictures into folders by date actually taken. The pictures will sort into folders with names the year taken like:

Folder: 2000

Inside the folder: Some pictures taken in the 2000.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> imageFiles= ... // Here you get the image path
Dictionary<int, List<string>> groupedPaths= ... //output dict
foreach(string str in imageFiles)
{
    FileInfo fi=new FileInfo(str);
    int year = fi.CreationTime.Year;
    if(!groupedPath.ContainsKey(year))
    {
       var list=new List<string>();
       list.Add(year, string);
       groupedPaths.Add(year, list);
    }
   else
   {   
       groupedPaths[year].Add(year, str);
   }
//Now you can process with foreach or use LINQ to group your images
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in groupedPaths)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to actually "sort" the files as in sort into folders. Like File.Move or something?

Comment: your use of the word "sort" is ambiguous, we can not sort into, but group into. sort is to reorder, but not grouping.

Comment: I tried it and it works but I am unfamiliar with the Dictionary and List class so I don't really know how to group the files into folders, but thanks for the new answer.

Comment: MSDN is always your close friend. Talk to "him",:)

Answer (score 1):

To get the date the picture was actually taken, you want to look at the Exif data.

This data is automatically read into the `PropertyItems` array when you use `Image.FromFile()`. You can then use another reference ([like this one)](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) to get the right codes for date info. You could also use [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43665/ExifLibrary-for-NET) to simplify reading the codes.

Not all images will have Exif data, so you may want to incorporate David's answer as a fallback.

Once you have the relevant date info, you can use `Directory.Create(year)` and `File.Move(oldPath, newPath)` to organize the files.